# Universities known for computational physics

Tags: education

I am very interested in computational physics and it is great lot of fun studying these topics. Since I am planning to go one semester abroad, I was wondering what universities are known for computational physics? Especially in regard to universities in the USA?

I am aware that computational physics is not a huge and independent branch of physics, but often integrated in the theoretical physics departments. But nevertheless I would very much appreciate any hints and suggestions on active and growing research groups.

EDIT: I was asked to add a little more detail on which topic I am an interested in.

That is a bit difficult, since I am in my 4.th Bachelor semester and know near to nothing about i.e. lattice quantum field theory. So its hard for me to say that I would prefer a specific research field.

I was hoping to find a kind of university/department, that is giving several lectures on computational physics or offers a broad spectrum of possibilities, so that I can specialize as soon as I obtain the theoretical background.

Comment: Just a small comment:  you may also find computational physics done in math departments.   The gap between physics and mathematics communities is not so wide here as it is in particle physics

Comment: There are vastly different branches of computational physics, and you should choose one to ask about. There's numerical General Relativity , numerical Quantum Chemistry , classical Statistical Mechanics/Monte-Carlo , lattice quantum field theory,  point particle dynamics/early universe simulations , symbolic computation a-la Schoonschip, quantum computation. Each is different, and each is centered at different places, and it is difficult to answer for all these subfields. Generally, all physics departments have a computation heavy workload, so it isn't much of a specialization.

Comment: You may want to look into computer graphics research. It's interesting and involves computational solids/fluids/foams/hairs/skins/fires etc.. It's often found in computer science departments (eg Stanford) or math departments (eg UCLA).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check my links to computational programs in the USA.

I know one here must provide direct information and not links. So, what I'll do is copy what I have in my links page, but provide a link to the page itself, since the actual links to the programs will not get copied when I copy the page here since the links are encoded. So, if you want the actual links, there are here

http://12000.org/my_notes/schools_ranking/index.htm

or you can google them from the information below

Here is the content of my page as of today

### Introduction

These are my collection of links to degrees in computational physics, computational science, computational engineering, Scientific computing, computational science engineering (CSE), or Applied and Computational Mathematics.

The differences is not that large, I think, since all these fields are really interdisciplinary.

it seems the term CSE (computational science and engineering) is becoming the most common term used, at least in the US, to describe programs of this nature.

### 1 Computational Physics specific

1. http://www.physics.ku.edu/~physics/graduate/comp.shtml University of Kansas has MS in computational physics and astronomy
2. http://www.physics.oregonstate.edu/~rubin/CPUG/ Oregon state univ. has computational physics but for undergraduate degree
3. http://undergrad-catalog.buffalo.edu/academicprograms/comphys.shtml Univ. of Buffalo, NY state, has computational physics but undergraduate degree.
4. http://www.csp.uga.edu/ Center for simulation physics at Univ. of Georgia has degree program
5. http://info.sjsu.edu/web-dbgen/catalog/departments/PHYS-section-8.htmlCalifornia state univ. San Jose has MS in computational physics
6. http://iacs.cua.edu/ The Catholic University of America, Institute for
   Astrophysics and Computational Sciences within the Physics dept has graduate program
7. http://earthscience.rice.edu/centers/ccg/ Rice university Computational Geophysics in the dept of earth science. They have MS and PhD programs.
8. http://www.chapman.edu/scst/computational-sciences/academic-programs/bs-physics-computational-science.aspx Chapman University, ORANGE, CA. Has a Bachelor of Science in
   Physics and Computational Science in the School of Computational Sciences.
9. http://www.uark.edu/misc/aaron5/index.html University of Arkansas, Computational Condensed Matter Physics (CCMP) Group. Seems to be just for research and visiting Scientists.No degrees offered.
10. http://www.cmu.edu/physics/research/computational/ Carnegie Mellon. Concentration area in Computational Physics.
11. http://www.uaf.edu/catalog/current/programs/physics_comp.html  UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS, MS in Computational physics.
12. http://www.memphis.edu/physics/grad_physics.htm University of Memphis,Tennessee. MS degree in physics with concentration in Computational physics

### 2 Other non-physics specific computational degrees

1. HTML New graduate program at UC Berkeley in Computational Science
       and Engineering.
2. HTML George Mason Univ. has graduate computational science program
   within the Physics dept now
   older site (before merging with the physics dept) HTML
3. HTML Stanford university. Mathematical and Computational Science program at Stanford offers programs leading to a B.S. degree, an honors option, and a minor. MCS is a multidisciplinary.
   Standford also has ICME (Institute for Computational and Mathematical Engineering) has its own M.S. and Ph.D. programs. interdisciplinary programs.
4. HTML State univ. of NY, Brockport, has undergraduate in
   computational science
5. HTML Univ. of Utah has MS degree in Computational Engineering and
   Science Program CSE. Univ. of Utah has also the HTML Scientific Computing and Imaging Institute. Accepts graduate students. interdisciplinary program. They also have a Computational Bioimaging Certificate Program. Univ. of Utah also has M.S. and Ph.D. in Computing, Graphics Track in the school of computing.
6. HTML Rice univ. has MS in computational science and engineering
7. HTML Rice univ. has also graduate program in computational and applied
   mathematics.
8. HTML The University of Southern Mississippi has graduate program in
   computational science
9. HTML Syracuse University has MS computational science
       and also certificates in computational science HTML
10. HTML Purdue Univ. Indiana, has graduate program in computational
    science and engineering CSE. Purdue also has Center for Computational & Applied Mathematics (CCAM), in the Math dept. Seems to accept graduate students.
11. HTML Department of Mathematics and Computer Science at the Courant
    Institute of Mathematical Sciences, New York University has MS in
    scientific computing
12. HTML HTML University of Michigan, College of Engineering, Lab for Scientific Computation, LaSC, has PhD in Scientific Computing.
13. HTML University of Michigan also has a Phd program in Scientific
     Computing The doctoral program in scientific computing was
     established by the University of Michigan in 1989.
14. HTML University of Illinois at Urbana Champaign (UIUC) has graduate program in Computational Science and Engineering CSE. HTML UIUC also has Scientific Computing Group in the dept of computer science. Graduate level.
15. HTML HTML Penn State has a graduate minor in Computational Science. Also Penn State has CCMA, the Center for Computational Mathematics and Applications, HTML. Not sure if they offer direct study programs.
16. HTML University of Texas At Austin has MS in Computational and
     Applied Mathematics
17. HTML I think the above program is now replaced by this: The
     university of Texas at Austin, Institute for Computational
     Engineering and Sciences (ICES), has a Computational Science,
     Engineering, and Mathematics (CSEM) graduate program. Formerly
     Computational and Applied Mathematics. An interdisciplinary
     program.
18. HTML San Diego State/Claremont Graduate University: PhD degree in
     computational science
19. HTML University of Minnesota has graduate program in scientific
     computation
20. HTML UC Davis has graduate program in CSE
21. HTML Michigan Tech university, MI, Has PhD in CSE
22. HTML HTML Indiana University Bloomington has minor in Scientific
     Computing
23. HTML HTML Florida state univ. has graduate Degrees In APPLIED AND COMPUTATIONAL MATHEMATICS and also a program in the Department of Scientific Computing.
24. HTML Princeton has a graduate program in Applied and Computational
     Mathematics (PCAM). There is also Princeton Institute for Computational Science and Engineering (PICSciE) but I am not sure it offers direct programs. It seems only for research.
25. HTML RPI has graduate program in CSE
26. HTML Univ. Of California, San Diego UCSD new graduate program called CSME (computational science mathematics and engineering. UCSD has also HTML the center for Computational Mathematics (CCoM).
27. HTML Caltech Computing + Mathematical Sciences Department offers an
     interdisciplinary program of graduate study in Applied and
     Computational Mathematics leading to a PhD degree.
28. HTML Clark Univ. Computational Science program
29. HTML Colorado state univ. Master of Science Degree in Mathematics
     with Specialization in Applied and Computational Mathematics
30. HTML Cornell Univ. Program in Computational Science and Engineering
31. HTML Duke Univ Computational Science, Engineering and Medicine
     program (CSEM)
32. HTML Georgia Institute of Technology, Computational Science and
     Engineering Division (CSE)
33. HTML Georgia state Univ. Dept of Mathematics has MS degree with
     concentrations in scientific computing.
34. HTML Louisiana State University, Center for Computation and
     Technology. Graduate level program.
35. HTML Louisiana Tech University, PhD program in Computational
     Analysis and Modeling (CAM)
36. HTML Loyola university has an MS in Scientific and Technical
     Computing
37. HTML MIT has MS degree program in in Computation for Design and
     Optimization in the center of computational engineering.
38. HTML Mississippi State University has graduate studies in
     Computational Engineering and high performance computing
39. HTML College of Engineering at North Carolina Agricultural and
     Technical State University has graduate program in Computational
     Science and Engineering (CSE)
40. HTML Center for Research in Scientific Computation (CRSC) at North
     Carolina state univ. has graduate studies program.
41. HTML Northwestern univ. has a graduate Engineering and applied
     mathematics program (ESAM) which seems to be computational based.
42. HTML Ralph Regula School of Computational Science at the Ohio
     Supercomputer Center has an undergraduate program in computational
     science.
43. HTML Ohio university has Master of Science in Mathematics -
     Computational Track
44. HTML Old Dominion University has a graduate program in modeling and
     simulation and has certificate program in computational science
     HTML
45. HTML Southern Methodist University Center for Scientific
     Computation has graduate studies.
46. HTML Stony brrok university, NY, has graduate program in
     COMPUTATIONAL APPLIED MATHEMATICS in the applied Math dept.
47. HTML Texas A&M Institute for Scientific Computation. Interesting
     courses, FEM and numerical HTML do not know what degrees they
     offer.
48. HTML UCLA Computational & Applied Mathematics, in the Math dept.
     Has graduate programs.
49. HTML Univ. Of California, Santa Barbra (UCSB) has CSE program for
     MS and PhD. multidisciplinary program.
50. HTML Univ of Chicago, dept of computer science, has a Computational
     Mathematics track of the Ph.D. program in Computer Science.
51. HTML The University of Arizona, Computational Science and Numerical
     Analysis program, in the Applied Math dept.
52. HTML University of Delaware. Graduate Program in Mathematical
     Computation, within the computer science dept. MS/PhD level.
53. HTML Also at University of Delaware, in the Math dept, a Numerical
     Analysis and Scientific Computing program. Courses seem really
     interesting. Graduate level.
54. HTML The Computational Sciences Initiative at the University of
     Houston (CSIUH) interdisciplinary graduate certificate program.
55. HTML University of Illinois at Chicago, Applied Mathematics and
     Computational Science (AMCS). Seems to be an MS program in the Math
     dept.
56. HTML University of Iowa. Applied Mathematical and Computational
     Sciences program (AMCS) is an interdisciplinary Ph.D. program in
     the Graduate College.
57. HTML University of Kentucky, dept of Math, has an Applied and
     Computational Mathematics graduate level program.
58. HTML University of Maryland. Applied Mathematics and Scientific
     Computation (AMSC) Graduate Program They also have a Scientific
     Computation Graduate Certificate Program.
59. HTML University of Maryland also has Center for Scientific
     Computation and Mathematical Modeling (CSCAMM). See the above AMSC
     program.
60. HTML Univ. of Massachusetts, darthmouth, has Mathematics Major with
     Computational Mathematics concetration.
61. HTML Univ. of Massachusetts, Lowell. Show a PhD program in
     Computational Mathematics
62. HTML University of Michigan-Dearborn has Master of Science Degree
     in Applied and Computational Mathematics in the department of
     Mathematics and Statistics.
63. HTML University of Minnesota Duluth, has Master of Science in
     Applied and Computational Mathematics in the dept of Mathematics
     and statistics.
64. HTML The University of Tennessee, Knoxville. Has Interdisciplinary
     Graduate Minor in Computational Science (IGMCS)
65. HTML University of Tennessee at Knoxville, Joint Institute for
     Computational Sciences has graduate program in Applied and
     Computational Mathematics through the math dept.
66. HTML University of Washington, seattle, College of Arts and
     Sciences, The Applied and Computational Mathematical Sciences
     (ACMS) program, multidisciplinary Bachelor of Science degree
     program in the College of Arts and Sciences.
67. HTML Western Michigan University, Math dept has Master of Science
     in Applied and Computational Mathematics
68. HTML Johns Hopkins University, Whiting School of Engineering, has
     Applied and Computational Mathematics at the MSc level.
69. HTML Chapman University, ORANGE, CA. offers MS and PhD in
     Computational Science.
70. HTML Central Washington Univ. WA. Has Computational Science Masters
     Program. Offered by the Computer Science Department.
71. HTML Boston University, The Boston University Center for
     Computational Science (CCS). CCS offers a Certificate in
     Computational Science to graduate students in engineering and
     science pursuing a Ph.D.